# Move some code from controller to factory in angular

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I must upload some file to server... I have some code in my controller, but the code is reusable.. So I would like to move it in a factory and then use the factory everytime I need it... I am not able to move this code to the factory.. If  I move it, nothing works anymore. Here the code I have in my controller and that I would like to move in the factory:

```
public_area.controller("SeguiAttivazioneController", function ($scope, SeguiAttivazioneService) {
    ...

    //an array of files selected
    $scope.files = [];

    //listen for the file selected event
    $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            //add the file object to the scope's files collection
            $scope.files.push(args.file);
        });
    });

    //the save method
    $scope.save = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/api/Upload",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            //This method will allow us to change how the data is sent up to the server
            // for which we'll need to encapsulate the model data in 'FormData'
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                //need to convert our json object to a string version of json otherwise
                // the browser will do a 'toString()' on the object which will result 
                // in the value '[Object object]' on the server.
                formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
                //now add all of the assigned files
                for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                    //add each file to the form data and iteratively name them
                    formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);
                }
                return formData;
            },
            //Create an object that contains the model and files which will be transformed
            // in the above transformRequest method
            data: { model: $scope.model, files: $scope.files }
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("success!");
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("failed!");
        });
    };
});
```

I have tried someting like this:

```
var public_area = angular.module("public-area");

public_area
.factory("uploadFactory", function ($scope, $http) {
        //an array of files selected
        $scope.files = [];

        //listen for the file selected event
        $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                //add the file object to the scope's files collection
                $scope.files.push(args.file);
            });
        });

       return {
           // upload: $resource("/api/EasyPay/")
           upload: function () {
               $http({
                   method: 'POST',
                   url: "/api/Upload",
                   headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                   //This method will allow us to change how the data is sent up to the server
                   // for which we'll need to encapsulate the model data in 'FormData'
                   transformRequest: function (data) {
                       var formData = new FormData();
                       //need to convert our json object to a string version of json otherwise
                       // the browser will do a 'toString()' on the object which will result 
                       // in the value '[Object object]' on the server.
                       formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
                       //now add all of the assigned files
                       for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                           //add each file to the form data and iteratively name them
                           formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);
                       }
                       return formData;
                   },
                   //Create an object that contains the model and files which will be transformed
                   // in the above transformRequest method
                   data: { model: $scope.model, files: $scope.files }
               }).
               success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   alert("success!");
               }).
               error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   alert("failed!");
               });
           }
       };
   });
```

But I have this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$scopeProvider%20%3C-%20$scope%20%3C-%20uploadFactory)

I think I do not have to say the scope inside the factory... and perhaps the listener must be inside the controller, even if I would prefer it stay in the factory...
Can anyone help me please? 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right you don't need $scope in your factory. Factory should be just a toolbox for your controller. Here is a example based on your code.

```
//factory
.factory("uploadFactory", function ($http) {
       return {
           // upload: $resource("/api/EasyPay/")
           upload: function (data) {
               $http({
                   method: 'POST',
                   url: "/api/Upload",
                   headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                  //some transformations....
                   data: { model: data.model, files: data.files }
               }).
               success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   alert("success!");
               }).
               error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   alert("failed!");
               });
           }
       };
   });

//controller
.controller("SeguiAttivazioneController", function ($scope, SeguiAttivazioneService, uploadFactory) {
    ...

    //an array of files selected
    $scope.files = [];

    //listen for the file selected event
    $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            //add the file object to the scope's files collection
            $scope.files.push(args.file);
        });

//call factory with $scope.files as 'data' argument
uploadFactory.upload($scope.files);

    });
```

Comment: there is no way to put the listener inside the factory?

Comment: the problem is that factory in AngularJS is not intended for this. if you want to use listener in one module - just leave the $http-handling code in controller

Comment: there is a way to move the success and the fail outside the factory so I can manage inside the controller?

Answer (score 1):

*$scope: Controllers are associated with an element in the DOM and so are provided with access to the scope. Other components (like services) only have access to the $rootScope service.* (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

You can use the $rootScope, but the best solution is change the upload function to accept the array of files, and make the observer of fileSelected in the controller or in a directive.

hope this helps!

Comment: the fileSelected is an event that is raise by a my custom directive... there is no way to manage it inside the factory self?